# How to auto-insert text from a cell into a part of an Excel formula (GETPIVOTDATA, specifically)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this formula:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sum of Daily_Income]",'After-Tax Income'!$A$3)
```

Above it is cell `B2` with "Daily" written into it.

I want to make it so that the "Daily" in "[Measures].[Sum of **Daily**_Income]" is replaced by a reference to the "Daily" in cell `B2`.

Something like:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sum of FORMULA(B1)_Income]",'After-Tax Income'!$A$3)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Use INDIRECT: `=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sum of" & INDIRECT(B1) & "_Income]"... `

Comment: @MátéJuhász No dice. It's returning "#REF!".

Comment: @MátéJuhász I put " " around B1, and it returned the value. However, I can't drag the cell access and get the desired result because the reference will remain the same throughout.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should be

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sum of " & B1 & "_Income]", 'After-Tax Income'!$A$3)
```

Be sure to include the space after “`of`”.